# C# get Values of all items in Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox whose display member is CompanyName and Value Member is CompanyID

i want to get the ID's of all the Companies(not just the selecteditems) to some Int values with a for loop determining the indices of the items.
C# winforms application.

something which could look like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
              int ID =  Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i].GetType().GetProperty("ValueMember").ToString());
            }
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: What kind of application you are targetting winform/wpf web ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 foreach (DataRowView drv in listBox1.Items)
        {
            int id= int.Parse(drv.Row[listBox1.ValueMember].ToString());
           //if you want to store all the idexes from your listbox, put them into an array 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you've databound an `IEnumerable<Company>` to the `ListBox`?

Then this should work:

```
int[] ids = new[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
int[] indices = listbox1.Items.Cast<Company>()
    .Select((company, index) => new { company, index})
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.company.ID))
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the type of the underlying item, you have to use some `Reflection` like this:

```
//Suppose your companyId is int
var valueMember = listBox1.Items[0].GetType().GetProperty(listBox1.ValueMember);
var companyIds = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>()
                         .Select(o=>(int)valueMember.GetValue(o,null))
                         .ToList();
```

Note that the code is applicable only if the `DataSource` of your `ListBox` is not `DataTable` because in that case, `ValueMember` is `ColumnName`, not Property name. In that case you can do something like this:

```
//In the case of using DataTable, the underlying item is a DataRowView
var companyIds = listBox1.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()
                         .Select(row=>(int)row.Row[listBox1.ValueMember])
                         .ToList();
```